# Full citation does not appear in Beamer slide footer

Tags: beamer, footer

I am facing a strange situation using Beamer

1. Bibliography is not printing in the last slide(s)
2. Only the reference key words are printed in the slide footer. But I need the full citation to be printed
3. If possible i would like to have the bibliography style ieeetr in the footers and last slide(s)

I am using TeX Studio
compiling chain used : pdflatex - bibliography - pdflatex - pdflatex

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Please find the MWE and bib file below

Thank you

JIM

============

%MWE
% !TEX TS–program = pdflatexmk
% !TEX root = IoT Technologies.tex
% !TeX program used: pdftex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand\item{\olditem\justifying}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\bibliographystyle{acm}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\bibliography{references}
\begin{document}
    \author{JIM}
    \title{\emph{IoT Technologies}}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Internet of Things}
        How do we define Internet of Things?
        \pause
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A network of items — each embedded with sensors — which are connected to the Internet - \footfullcite{minerva2015towards}
            \pause 
            \item The interconnection via the internet of computing devices embedded in everyday objects, enabling them to send and receive data. - \text{Oxford Dictionary}
        \end{itemize}
    
    \end{frame}
    

    \begin{frame}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

===================================

%references.bib

```
@article{minerva2015towards,
  title={Towards a definition of the Internet of Things (IoT)},
  author={Minerva, Roberto and Biru, Abyi and Rotondi, Domenico},
  journal={IEEE Internet Initiative},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1--86},
  year={2015},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

=====================================

% Output images
[image: Please note that only the cite key words appear in the footer rather than the full citation]

%TeX Studio messages
Error: One command expansion invalid.
Parent Command: bibliography
Primary Command: bibliography

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_EfgnBh".tex

Process exited normally

% TeX Studio issues
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:

%Editor configuration
[image: Editor configuration]

Comment: `\addbibresource` needs the file name of your `.bib` file with file extension. So `\addbibresource{references}` should presumably be `\addbibresource{references.bib}`. You also need to run Biber on your document so that a whole compile cycle is pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 to configure your editor for Biber. (If you use `pdflatexmk` that should run Biber for you automatically, but it is not clear to me whether you actually ensure that `pdflatexmk` is used as suggested by the file header).

Comment: Note that your `reference.bib` as shown does not contain a reference called `ieee` and that you *probably* want to use `\footfullcite` and not just `\footcite` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, infact I followed the steps in the above stack exchange post Now I have made the following changes:
\addbibresource{references.bib} , used \footfullcite{} , removed the invalid reference from tex file. But I get the same error messages and the old output itself. The error messages are posted below          Error: One command expansion invalid.
    Parent Command: bibliography
    Primary Command: bibliography

Comment: Please update the code with the changes you have made (it still says `\addbibresource{references}`, which is incorrect, and now uses `\footcite` where you said you had used `\footfullcite` in your last comment). Please also add the exact message of the error to the question. The error message you mention does not sound like a LaTeX or Biber error, so maybe you did not configure your editor correctly. Please show a screenshot of your editor config and compare it again against https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: I get an error message when biber is run on the tex file 
Command txs:///biber not defined

Comment: OK, then something with your editor configuration is wrong. Please explain exactly how you tried to set your editor up for Biber. Add pictures if that helps. (Please do not say "I followed the steps in <link>")

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, how to configure the biber command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120494/discussion-between-joaquim-and-moewe).

Comment: For some reason your Biber configuration in the editor has `<unknown>`. It should say `biber %` instead.

Comment: If you have not installed Biber yet you may have to do that with (`sudo`) `apt install biber`.

Comment: Thank you so much. apt install biber did the trick. I had installed bibtex-extra (apt install texlive-bibtex-extra) and assumed that biber would be part of it.